# Reproduce the beamer miniframes environment

Tags: counters

I would like to reproduce the `miniframes` features of beamer, with the bullets per section even though it would concern the chapters per part. I need a counter counting the total number of chapters in each part of the document. Based on [`beamerbasicmisc`](http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbasemisc.sty) there is probably some code to be taken from the following lines:

```
\def\headcommand#1{\global\advance\beamer@totalheads by1\relax%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname @@head\the\beamer@totalheads\endcsname{#1}}
\def\dohead{\beamer@headcounter=0\relax\loop\ifnum\beamer@headcounter<\beamer@totalheads%
  \advance\beamer@headcounter by1\relax%
  \csname @@head\the\beamer@headcounter\endcsname\repeat}
```

but later, needed information is written in the .aux file. Is there a simpler way to achieve this?